# Does Zend Framework turns off declaring variables as global?

Tags: php, zend-framework, global-variables

I am integrating third party code into the web application I am writing in Zend Framework.

The code I want to integrate declares variables as global. It works on its own, but not when I include it within Zend Framework. Initially I suspected that there is something in Zend Framework that is disabling the declaration of global variables. I have the following test code in a controller:

```
public function testglobalAction()
{
   $a = 1;
   function b()
   {
      global $a;
      echo $a*2;
   }

   b();
}
```

When I ran it prints out 0, as opposed to 2. On top of that running the same code on its own in the same web server prints out 2.

I understand that I could replace all the global instances to use Zend Registry. However, a grep showed me that there are roughly 700 lines I have to change, so it is not feasible at the moment.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Globals are not a good idea in PHP. Zend is doing you a favor.

Comment: I knew that would be the first comment/answer I'd get with this question! :) But I really integrate this code into my application.

Comment: Provide the code as you run it from the controller. I don't see anything related to ZF in your sample. Oversimplification = we can't help you.

Comment: Edited the question with the controller action. It is a really simple code as I am just trying to test if my theory is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your original $a variable isn't global.

Any variable declared inside of a method is local to that method, **unless** it's been previously declared global in the current scope.

Try this

```
public function testglobalAction()
{
    global $a;
    $a = 1;
    function b()
    {
        global $a;
        echo $a*2;
    }

    b();
}
```

Comment: Additionally, PHP scoping prevents access to outer local variables within inner functions/calls, despite the fact that those variables are still in active memory and accessible to the application flow once the inner function exits.

Comment: Almost eyelidlessness.  Prior to PHP 5.3, "inner" functions didn't exist.  When you define a function inside a method as above, you're actually defining a function in the global scope (if you called testglobalAction you'd get a Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare b().  PHP 5.3 introduced real lambda functions and closures, and requires you to specify which variables you want to import from the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

No. Zend Framework doesn't disable globals, as it is not possible. The $GLOBALS array is controlled by the php.ini `register_globals` directive. It cannot be changed at runtime using `ini_set`.

See the [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) for reference.

**Note:** Check your .htaccess files for any per-directory `php_value` overrides.

Comment: I did try turning on register_globals and I get the same result. There are no php_value overriding the directive either.

It is funny that I have a test file in the same web server that prints out 2 which is the expected result. However, when I run that code in a controller I get 1.